# Could someone please talk me through this simple function and why it is behaving this way (pointers,C++)

Tags: c++, pointers

I have 2 snippets of code, I am trying to pass a pointer into a function which is working for me, however when I deref the pointer, set to 10000 then increment I do not get the desired output.

[image: undesired output, where does the 4 come from!]

```
#include<iostream>


 void ReturnArray(int *matrix);

 int array;



int main() {

ReturnArray(&array);


return(0);
}


void ReturnArray(int *matrix) {

int x{ 0 };

for (x=0; x < 10; ++x){


*matrix = 10000;
++matrix;


std::cout << *matrix << "\n";
}

 }
```

However, when I increment the address of the pointer then set the value to 10000 the output is as expected..

[image: Desired output]

```
#include<iostream>


void ReturnArray(int *matrix);

int array;



int main() {

ReturnArray(&array);


return(0);
}


void ReturnArray(int *matrix) {

int x{ 0 };

for (x=0; x < 10; ++x){


    ++matrix;
    *matrix = 10000;



std::cout << *matrix << "\n";
}

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not an array it's a single `int` variable. You are writing past the variable and trashing memory. It's **undefined behavior** and nobody cares about the result because it doesn't have to do anything reasonable.

Comment: Unrelated, but you absolutely need to learn how to format code consistently. Just get inspired by the samples in your C++ text book.

Comment: Hi,  Can you recommed and  textboook?

Answer (score 2):

`array` is a single integer, you are trying to use it as a 10 element array, this is undefined behaviour. Any result is possible.

Change `array` to be an array:

```
int array[10];
```

To make your code print the correct values you need to increment after printing:

```
for (x=0; x < 10; ++x) {
  *matrix = 10000;
  std::cout << *matrix << "\n";
  ++matrix;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, I was trying to pass by ref, using the name of the array  as the address ident, so while not defined as an array, functionality is the same.

I will digest your answer and conduct like this in future!

Comment: No. the functionality isn't the same, you can't magically change an integer into an integer array by taking a pointer to it (`&array` is making a pointer to `array`, it is nothing to do with passing by reference), by using it as an array you are overwriting memory not allocated to your `array` variable, it might appear to work but it is undefined behavuiour so your code is likely to crash or otherwise behave strangely in the future

Answer (score -3):

**ok so figured it out, I am setting the value after deref, then changing the address so when cout is called there is nothing initialized at that new address...**

I guess my next question then is.. where is the 4 coming from? is it termed garbage data or is there a reason it is not 0?

thank-you for helping me understand.

Comment: All the standard says is that this will invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), but yes I would probably say the memory is garbage or uninitialized.

Comment: All or most of this answer is not actually answering the question and should be added as clarification to the question instead. You can edit your question by clicking "edit" under it or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60539353/edit). The first part of this answer doesn't really answer the question, because no matter in which order the two statements are put, the program has undefined behavior in both cases.